# Deploying NodeJS/Babel/Grunt app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, gruntjs, browserify, babeljs

I'm trying to deploy my project on Heroku. I've been able to `heroku open` the app and see it but I get a 404 on my `bundle.js`. The app is on github [here](https://github.com/gh0st/ncps-mms). The app is on heroku [here](https://ncps-mms.herokuapp.com).

I've tried making sure my dependencies are all there regarding babel, babelify, grunt, etc. But I must be still missing something.

I don't get any errors after my `git push heroku` but I still get my 404.

Comment: You can check log detail of your code by command: heroku logs -n 200

Answer (score 0):

I am able to recreate this locally as well.  This is what I get when I run your `postinstall` script code:

```
$ npm run postinstall

> ncps-mms@0.0.0 postinstall ncps-mms
> gulp transpile --gulpfile client/gulpfile.babel.js

[00:18:43] Requiring external module babel-register
[00:18:43] Working directory changed to ncps-mms/client
(node:30276) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
[00:18:43] Using gulpfile ncps-mms/client/gulpfile.babel.js
[00:18:44] Starting 'transpile'...

Error:  Cannot find module './controllers/members-detail-controller' from 'ncps-mms/client/src'

[00:18:44] Finished 'transpile' after 184 ms
```

I see this error:

`Error:  Cannot find module './controllers/members-detail-controller' from 'ncps-mms/client/src'`

The members-detail-controller is missing - See: https://github.com/gh0st/ncps-mms/tree/master/client/src/controllers.

If I comment out the following lines, https://github.com/gh0st/ncps-mms/blob/master/client/src/app.js#L4 and https://github.com/gh0st/ncps-mms/blob/master/client/src/app.js#L15 then run `npm run postinstall` again, the gulp tasks run without errors.  I am then able to start the server without the 404's on bundle.js.

Comment: So running `npm run watch` is supposed to start the transpile process and watch for changes to source. The missing module isn't a deal breaker and compiles/runs without it.